Switching from enterprise to community edition
I am trying to switch from enterprise edition to community edition in anypoint studio which I am using 7.15 version.But not able to switch . Can anyone suggest the steps to switch and deploy the application community edition runtime
not able to switch from enterprise edition to community edition

"not able to switch" is not a helpful description of the issue. Please read [ask] then [edit] your question to provide details.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
